Baby Rudin 1.6(c)
Working the exercice in my copy of the french translation. I looked everywhere and no one seems to be asking this question.
The problem, in french at least, says $B(x)$ is a subset or rational numbers of the form $b^r$ such that r is a rational number less than x. I'm reading this somewhat like:
$B(x) = \{ b^r \in \mathbb Q \mid r \in \mathbb Q, r < x\}$
Now every answer to this question casually ignores this is a subset of $\mathbb Q$ and as such it is not clear at all to me that this set is even non-empty (at least with what we know at this point in this book). For all I know, depending on $b > 1$, every $b^r$ for $r$ rational could be algebraic non-rational and every $b^x$ for $x$ real could be rational $\cup$ transcendental.
So is the english version omiting that detail or a typo? On assuming $x \in \mathbb R$ is such that $x < b^r$, I'm having a hard time producing rational numbers of the form $b^t, t \in \mathbb Q$ between $x$ and $b^r$ showing $b^r$ must be the supremum.

You haven't said what $x$ is.

You aren't saying what you are asked to prove, either, only the definition.

I suspect that this is attempting to define expressions of the form $b^x$ for arbitrary real $x$, in which case it's only $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ with no requirement on $b^r$.

Hi @ThomasAndrews, it is a question about the orignal version of the book. B(x) is well defined, x can be any real number and b > 1.

You still have t said what the question is. "Now every answer to this question..." What question?  You've written down a definition of $B(x).$Put details in the question, not comments, because a person should know what your question is without reading your comments.

When you say $b^r\in \mathbb{Q}$, I think either you are misunderstanding something or the French translation is faulty.
I’m looking at my English copy right now. Exercise 6 of Chapter 1 starts by saying

Fix $b > 1$

Then part c says

(c) If $x$ is real, define $B(x)$ to be the set of all numbers $b^t$, where $t$ is rational and $t \leq x$

Notice there’s no assumption that $b$ is rational, thus $b^t$ is not constrained to be rational.
BTW, my French, though not fluent, is probably good enough for math, so if you post the French text I might be able to discern a translation issue (if it exists)

Ok thank you, it is the french copy that is faulty as it says to consider rational numbers $b^t$ with $t \in \mathbb Q$, so both restrictions.

Yikes, sounds like it may be a pretty bad translation job. Your English seems good enough that you might want to consider working from the English version as your primary source.

My experience is that math terminology tends to be similar Latin-origin words in both English and French. For example “derivative” and “derivee” (versus “ableitung” in German)
